# Layout of plots with a unique legend using ggplot

Tags: r, layout, plot, ggplot2, grid-layout

I was trying to create a layout with plots sharing the same legend. The legend is on the top of the first plot, however, the next plot has a different scale. How can I solve this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = "Data")) +
  stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "Regression"), method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1) +
  labs(shape = "", linetype = "") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10),
        legend.position = "top")
,
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10))
)
```

[image: IMAGE 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use `grid.arrange`, but here's a solution using my cowplot package. The idea is to separate the legend out from the plot and then put the three elements into one column. A similar approach would work with `grid.arrange`, I assume.

```
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = "Data")) +
  stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "Regression"), method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1) +
  labs(shape = "", linetype = "") +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10),
        legend.position = "top")

p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10))

legend <- get_legend(p1)
plot_grid(legend, p1 + theme(legend.position = "none"), p2,
          ncol=1, rel_heights = c(0.1, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Whats exactly the function of `cowplot`?

Comment: Well, I mostly wrote it to make combined plots. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html).

Comment: Let me ask you something. I used the `theme_set(theme_cowplot(font_size = 8))`, but the `annotate` text is not appearing in this size. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please post as separate question, with example code.

Answer (score 3):

If the plots also have the same axes labels, facet_wrap may be a good option.

```
library(ggplot2)

data = rbind(data.frame("id" = 1, mpg), data.frame("id" = 2, mpg))

ggplot(data, aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = "Data")) +
    stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "Regression"), method = "lm", 
          formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = 1) +
    labs(shape = "", linetype = "") +
    theme_classic() + 
    facet_wrap(~id, ncol = 1 ) +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
    aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10),
    legend.position = "top",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()) #these two lines remove the facet strips
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

`grid.arrange` doesn't try to align plot panels; it's a generic function meant for all kinds of grid graphics, and in this case since the top plot has a legend it gets shrunk to fit in the available space (by default 1/2 of the page here). For the specific case of ggplots I would use `egg::ggarrange`,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

ggarrange(

  ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = "Data")) +
    stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "Regression"), method = "lm", 
                formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = 1) +
    labs(shape = "", linetype = "") +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
          aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10),
          legend.position = "top")
  ,
  ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 1) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
                formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, colour = 1, size = 0.5) +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
          aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 10))
)
```